# App Group - Today Extension Identifier

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I've created a today Extension which should share Data with the main app. The Problem is the App is in the AppStore and I can't change the Bundle identifier for this so the App Group throws the error:

[Error App Group Main Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJPC.png)

How can I fixed this without rename the Bundle Identifier from the main app?

Answer (score 0):

You must update your App Id with the app group service, and your app entitlement file with app group too. There's nothing complicated in your errors

Comment: but how can i do this?

Comment: developer.apple.com -> account -> connect your developer account -> go to manage app ids

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It can not be solved in Xcode it should be edited on the developer homepage where u can manage all he profiles.